# Cannot create contact with custom data in schema extensions, group works

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have created a schema extension for group and contacts.

First Issue: I can create new group with custom data using the extension but not with contact. I get the following error when I try to create a new contact with custom data in schema extension.

```
{
    "error": 
    {
        "code": "RequestBodyRead",
        "message": "The property 'extcivhhslh_sbtest1' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Contact'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.",
        "innerError": 
        {
            "request-id": "5686a76f-f016-47aa-82a3-acd9ab57e3ae",
            "date": "2017-06-14T05:44:22"
        }
    }
}
```

Issue#2: As per the 5th example in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups I should be able to get the custom data in the extensions. In my testing I don't get back the custom data in the extension.

The extension looks like the following:

```
{
      "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions",
      "value": [
        {
          "id": "extcivhhslh_sbtest1",
          "description": "SbGraph test extensions",
          "targetTypes": [
            "contact",
            "group"
          ],
          "status": "Available",
          "owner": "da033fe6-d48e-435d-8014-e98a4b166900",
          "properties": [
            {
              "name": "customerType",
              "type": "String"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of ``GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions?$filter=id eq 'extcivhhslh_sbtest1'`` ?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Schema extensions cannot be used while creating the contact. Once the contact is created, you can patch it using schema extension value.

2 - Please verify that you have specified $select=extcivhhslh_sbtest1 while querying for /groups to get the extension values (along with other $select properties that you are interested in).

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: Still the same error while updating contact. Selecting the extension value also doesn't return the custom data.